# How can I count a subquery with group by

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm new here, I'm french, apologize my English please.

I have a grid with a HQL source.
The first HQL's query send the count of records, and the second query the data.
But the result of the first query isn't equal to the number of record of the second query.

The first query (return 26 records) :

```
SELECT 
    resou.res_book.res_book_id as record,
    strset.str_set_cd as room, 
    concat(coalesce(person.firstname, ' '), ' ', coalesce(person.lastname, ' ')) as name, 
    prod_h.d_from_d as start_date,
    prod_h.d_to_d as end_date,
    (SUM(prod_h.amt_total_ivat) - SUM(pay_l.amt_paymt)) as total
FROM Com_site as site
inner join site.com_bu as bu
inner join bu.com_activ as activ
inner join activ.inv_head as head
inner join head.inv_person as person
inner join person.res_rooming as rooming
inner join rooming.res_resou as resou
inner join resou.str_set as strset
inner join person.inv_prod_h as prod_h
inner join head.inv_pay_l as pay_l
inner join prod_h.pdt_prod as prod
WHERE
    head.tp_folio_tp = 0 and
    prod_h.d_to_d <= '2020-07-01' and
    site.com_site_id = 1 and
    prod_h.inv_accou_itm.inv_accou_itm_id is null and
    prod.b_rent_bl = false and
    '2020-07-01' between resou.d_from_d and resou.d_to_d
GROUP BY 
    head.inv_head_id
    , person.firstname
    , person.lastname
    , strset.str_set_cd
    , resou.res_book.res_book_id
    , prod_h.d_from_d
    , prod_h.d_to_d
    , head.tp_folio_tp
    , prod.pdt_prod_id
```

And the second query (return 1 record but the value is 316 (not 26)) :

```
select 
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(head.inv_head_id) as counted
    from site.com_bu as bu
    inner join bu.com_activ as activ
    inner join activ.inv_head as head
    inner join head.inv_person as person
    inner join person.res_rooming as rooming
    inner join rooming.res_resou as resou
    inner join resou.str_set as strset
    inner join person.inv_prod_h as prod_h
    inner join head.inv_pay_l as pay_l
    inner join prod_h.pdt_prod as prod
    WHERE
        head.tp_folio_tp = 0 and
        prod_h.d_to_d <= '2020-07-01' and
        site.com_site_id = 1 and
        prod_h.inv_accou_itm.inv_accou_itm_id is null and
        prod.b_rent_bl = false and
        '2020-07-01' between resou.d_from_d and resou.d_to_d
) as counted
from Com_site as site
```

I tried:
`COUNT(COUNT(head.inv_head_id)), COUNT(*the subquery here*)`

but nothing works...

Anyone can please help me ?

Thank's you in advance.

Comment: Did you try to add the `GROUP BY` in the second query? It might filter out some duplicate records coming from `1:N` relationships.

Comment: What do you expect from the second query? You say it should return the data but there is a count

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you want to determine the count first and then query all the data, you could just determine the count by counting the amount of fetched entities, so there is no need for a second query.

In case you are trying to implement pagination, I can recommend you take a look at [Blaze-Persistence](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#core-quick-start) which has excellent support for [creating efficient count queries from a base query](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/core/manual/en_US/index.html#count-query) and [bounded counting](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/core/manual/en_US/index.html#bounded-counting), but also supports various paginations techniques: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/core/manual/en_US/index.html#pagination

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping me ! I found that my query is tottaly wrong, so I rewrote the query without group by, and it's works ! The first query send the correct count of record of the second query.